# Programmatically disable 'Required Checkout' using sharepoint webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

How does one programatically disable the 'Required Checkout' field of a column inside a sharepoint document library using sharepoint webservices?

Preferably using C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not possible via the classic SharePoint WebServices, but if you are using SharePoint 2010, it should be possible via the new Client Object Model:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.forcecheckout.aspx

Comment: How about the "Required" Field of a column? (in moss 2007)

Comment: You can change if a column is required by using the Lists.asmx UpdateList method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelist(v=office.12).aspx (see the example below "updateFields")